# public function in class doesn't work properly

Tags: android, class, oop, public-method

I have a "movie" class and a public function getName(), but the function doesn't return anything, and the logcat is just blank.

```
public class movie {

    public String name45;
    int dvd_no ;

    public void addData( String name1 , int dvd_no1) 
    {
                this.name45=name1 ;
            this.dvd_no = dvd_no1 ; 

            Log.d("constructor name1", name1);

            Log.d("constructor name45", name45);

    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name45 ;
    }

}
```

This is an activity which uses this method - the list always has blank entries.

```
public class MoviesList extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.movieslist);
        ListView lvAllMoviesList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.allmovieslist);

          ArrayList<String> moviesNames = new ArrayList<String>();
            // go through list of members and compare name with given name
            for(movie movie : MovieReg_activity.movies) {
          String name =  movie.getName();
          Log.d("Movie Name list", movie.getName());
                    moviesNames.add(name);

            }


        ArrayAdapter<String> AllMovieList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MoviesList.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, moviesNames);
        lvAllMoviesList.setAdapter(AllMovieList);
    }

}
```

the code which generate objects and add values to it

```
public class MovieReg_activity extends Activity {

    public static List<movie> movies = new ArrayList<movie>();

    String movName ;
    int dvdNo ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mov_reg_layout);
        EditText etmovie_name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etmovname);
        EditText etdvd_no = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etdvds);
        Button btMovie_submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btmovsubmit);

        movName= etmovie_name.getText().toString();
    //  dvdNo = Integer.parseInt(etdvd_no.getText().toString()); // to string then to int :)

        btMovie_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int x=0 ;
                movie movie = new movie() ;
                movie.addData(movName, dvdNo);
                movies.add(x,movie );
                x++ ;
                int size =movies.size() ;
                Toast.makeText(MovieReg_activity.this, "no of movies added :"+size , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: How shall we debug this? We don't know how you use it.

Comment: @DaveNewton sorry .. i will edit the post

Comment: @DaveNewton i meant to test it by logcat !

Comment: This doesn't help. Where do you *set* the values?

Comment: @DaveNewton ok i will edit it

Comment: @DaveNewton added the code .. take a look :)

Comment: Your approach here seems a little risky - how are you going to insure that the Activity which loads this static ArrayList always runs before the Activity which reads it?  Of course, there can't be no return value, if it is null, that will be the return value.  Perhaps that code is never executing.

Comment: @ChrisStratton first i add movies to that arraylist and with every movie added as you see i check the size() of arraylist ..

Comment: Not in your MovieList activity you don't - you are *assuming* the other Activity has been run first in the lifetime of this process, but  I don't see what you are doing to make sure that is the case.

Comment: @ChrisStratton i think there's a misunderstanding .. i tested that by making the list views the objects themselves not their names and it worked well,, beside it's not the only problem caused by that method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in taking the data from the user in the MovieReg_activity

and its solved by putting those two lines

```
 EditText etmovie_name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etmovname);
 movName= etmovie_name.getText().toString();
```

inside the button listener to be like this

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                int x=0 ;
                EditText etmovie_name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etmovname);
                movName= etmovie_name.getText().toString();
                movies.add(new movie(movName , dvdNo) );
                String name3= movie.getName() ;
                x++ ;
                int size =movies.size() ;
                Toast.makeText(MovieReg_activity.this, "no of movies added :"+size , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `TAG` parameter for the logs to the first string, try:

```
Log.d("DEBUG", "constructor name1 " + name1);
Log.d("DEBUG", "constructor name45 " + name45);
```

And then set your logcat filter to `DEBUG`

Comment: Doesn't explain the lack of return value though.

Comment: Nevertheless it explains why his logcat is blank, and may very well show it is outputting a value.